# Google chart - how to change a css property for the whole table

Tags: javascript, css, overloading, google-visualization

I have a css definition that sets "table border-collapse:collapse" for a div. In that div I display a Google Orgchart that innherits this property and then cause a display problem when rendering the chart.

How can I remove/overload this property for the chart, given that it's generated dynamically hence I can't use inline properties.

EDIT : The code generated by google's js is :

```
<table class="google-visualization-orgchart-table" dir="ltr" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"`>
```

I have tried to add in my file :

```
.google-visualization-orgchart-table {
border-collapse:separate;
}
```

But no effects ..

Still using Chrome's inspect feature, I can see that the following css is causing this :

```
#main-content table {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

With main-content being my DIV. When I manually uncheck this "border-collapse" property in Chrome, it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: If you just look at the documentation from Google. You will see that you can add classes with the cssClassNames option: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#Configuration_Options

Comment: It seems that the cssClassNames option only applies to table elements, not the table itself.

Comment: All these options make your table. To edit `google-visualization-table-table` just add `.google-visualization-table-table` in your css file and give priority with the `!important`

Comment: Allright, the thing I forgot was " !important" directive .. I thought that it was not necessary as it's defined in the page itself, but dynamic content is  higher priority it seems. Thank you both.

Comment: So why do i have it working? http://jsfiddle.net/6bWnW/

Comment: Add the !important to .google-visualization-orgchart-table

Comment: I am still fighting with this.  I have put important in the div contains the div that will be replaced.  I have specialized it for exact classes google uses on its nodes and lines even.  All with no joy.  All not doing the same thing as setting border-collapse: separate in chrome inspector.  
Changing in in Chrome works.  Targeting it in my imbedded css does not do it. 

It is hard to tell exactly where it came from in the inspector after all the css has been crammed together.   Strangely the standalone sample for what I am doing, an orgchart, doesn't have this artifact.

Comment: Bizarre.  Brought it up in firefox and there it works just fine.   WTH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done in similar situations is use Firebug for Firefox to find the name, id, or class of the item that is causing the problem then add css for that element in my stylesheet.

If you do not already have Firebug on the latest version of Firefox, get it here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/us

EXAMPLE:

Say the id of the element is googleTable

```
#googleTable{
 border-collapse:separate !important;
}
```

Be Sure to include !important to ensure no inheritance takes place.

Comment: Hi ! I tried this way (I edited my post to show some details) but without success.. Anything wrong in my code ? I was wondering if the problem could be that when my custom css for "google-visualization-orgchart-table" is loaded, the Google JS is not yet loaded into the page..

Comment: Add !important and be sure to set the width of the .google table to what it was before inheriting the 100%.